# Laplace transform of piecewise function

Tags: definite-integrals, laplace-transform

I have a piecewise function f(t), and I'm trying to get it's laplace transform.
When I do it manually, i'm getting a different result than with Maple.

$$
f(t)=\!\cases{{t}^{2}&$0<t$  and  $t<1$\cr 0&otherwise\cr}{
{\rm }}{}
$$

My manual approach consists of the following steps:
$$
F(s)=\int _{0}^{\infty }\!f \left( t \right) {{\rm e}^{-st}}{dt}
$$
$$
=\int _{0}^{1}\!{t}^{2}{{\rm e}^{-st}}{dt}+\int _{1}^{\infty }\!0{dt}
$$
Using integration by parts, with $u=t^2$, $u'=2t$, $v=e^{-st}/(-s)$, $v'=e^{-st}$
$$
\int _{}^{}\!u{\it v'}{}=uv-\int _{}^{}\!{\it u'}\,v{}
$$
$$
(1)=-{\frac {{t}^{2}{{\rm e}^{-st}}}{s}}-\int _{0}^{1}\!-{\frac {2t{
{\rm e}^{-st}}}{s}}{dt}  $$
$$
=-{\frac {{t}^{2}{{\rm e}^{-st}}}{s}}+2\,{\frac {\int _{0}^{1}\!t{
{\rm e}^{-st}}{dt}}{s}}
$$
Again, integration by parts for the new integral we got from the previous integration by parts.

With $u=t$,  $u'=1$,  $v=e^{-st}/(-s)$,  $v'=e^{-st}$
$$
(2)=2\,{\frac {\int _{0}^{1}\!t{
{\rm e}^{-st}}{dt}}{s}}=(2/s)(-{\frac {t{{\rm e}^{-st}}}{s}}-\int _{0}^{1}\!-{\frac {{{\rm e}^{-st}}
}{s}}{dt})
$$
After solving (2), I substitute it into (1), which gives me:
$$=-{\frac {{t}^{2}{{\rm e}^{-st}}}{s}}-2\,{\frac {t{{\rm e}^{-st}}}{{s}^
{2}}}+2\,{\frac {{{\rm e}^{-s}}}{{s}^{3}}}+2\,{s}^{-3}$$

$$
={\it Eval} \left( -{\frac {{t}^{2}{{\rm e}^{-st}}}{s}}-2\,{\frac {t{
{\rm e}^{-st}}}{{s}^{2}}},t=1 \right) -{\it Eval} \left( -{\frac {{t}^
{2}{{\rm e}^{-st}}}{s}}-2\,{\frac {t{{\rm e}^{-st}}}{{s}^{2}}},t=0
 \right) +2\,{\frac {{{\rm e}^{-s}}}{{s}^{3}}}+2\,{s}^{-3}$$
$$=-{\frac {{{\rm e}^{-s}}}{s}}+2\,{\frac {{{\rm e}^{-s}}}{{s}^{3}}}+2\,{
s}^{-3}
$$

However, the laplace-transform function of Maple gives me the following: 
$${\frac {2-{{\rm e}^{-s}} \left( {s}^{2}+2\,s+2 \right) }{{s}^{3}}}$$
And I can't figure out what went wrong..

Thank you.

Comment: Check your first limit where $t=1$, you should end with $-s^{-2}(se^{-s}+2e^{-s})$

Comment: @Autolatry, i did and i still become the same result.

Comment: The integral, before the substitution of 1 and 0, does not have a $2s^{-3}$ term.

Comment: Also, the $\frac{1}{s^2}$ term in the first eval has disappeared somehow.

Comment: @Paul, I recalculated it, and I did forget that term. This result only differs on plus-negative terms. So I'll be focussing on that now. Thanks for the help !